# trouble to vertically and horizontally center <img> inside <a> in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm having trouble with centering images that are inside `<a>` tag. To center all of them horizontally, I set `justify-content: center;` to `<span>` container that contains mentioned images.

Then I set `align-self: center;` for both `<a>` and `<img>` elements, it works just perfect in Chrome and Firefox browsers, but **in IE** I'm **not able** to **center images vertically**.

And important is that I cannot change the flow of the elements, I mean that `<span>` must contain `<a>` and it contains `<img>`.

You can find an example on created there -> [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ucuuv2uw/8/fiddle).

Comment: who cares about IE?

Comment: unfotunetly I do a little bit ;)

Comment: http://howtocenterincss.com/ Problem solved xD

Comment: For IE, you need to give the container an explicit height, not just a min-height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

**CSS**

```
.multiimage {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 50px 0px;
}

.multiimage a img {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

img elements can be centered with text-align: center; weird I know.